Cookies are not being sent from server side
Server side:
    const app = express();
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5173", methods: ["GET", "POST"], credentials: true }));
    
    export const test = (req, res) => {
      return res
        .cookie("Test", "TESTCOOKIE", { maxAge: 100000000, secure: true, sameSite: "none" })
        .status(200)
        .json("cookies sent");
    };
    
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get("/test", test);

Client side:
  axios.get("http://localhost:9999/api/test");

The problem: There is no cookie in the browser. I am not getting any cookie
What I want: I want to receive cookie from the server and store them in a user's browser
What've I tried:

I used Insomnia (an app for server requests) and it is working, I
could get the test cookie.
I opened the "http://localhost:9999/api/test" in my browser and it worked as well.


You need to set withCredentials in your axios request (the link is to XMLHttpRequest documentation, which axios uses under the hood, I have no clue how to set it in axios, but axios does have its own basic "documentation" that may or may not help)
